# Questions on asymmetric nature of mass and stiffness matrices

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, free-body-diagram, vibrations

**EDIT**: I now know the answer to my second question after re-reading relevant parts of my textbook and reading Eli's answer.

I was under the impression that mass and stiffness matrices are always symmetric (as I have been taught in my course and in textbook as well) but while solving questions from another textbook, I came to know that the matrices can be asymmetric as well. This has confused me now.

My first question is why then have we been taught that they are always symmetric all this while? Now, I had a look at [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95627/can-a-mass-matrix-be-asymmetric) on [Physics.SE] and the first answer to this makes it clear that it is only the symmetric component of a matrix $\left(\frac{M+M^T}{2}\right)$ that contributes to the kinetic or potential energy through the quadratic form because $x^TAx=0\forall x$ for a skew symmetric matrix.

> So is it that, when being taught, we are told that the mass and stiffness matrices have to always be symmetric because they implicitly have in mind that even if they are asymmetric, it is only the symmetric component that is of importance and which contributes to kinetic and potential energy?

This leads me to my second question, which can well be asked independently as well but I thought this ties in well here, so I am asking it here (I will make a separate post for this if users think that is better). How do we know that the matrices $M$ and $K$ appearing in $T=\frac{1}{2}\dot u^TM\dot u$ and $V=\frac{1}{2}u^TKu$ are indeed the matrices which will also appear in the final matrix form of equations of motion for a multi DOF linear system, i.e., $M\ddot x+Kx=0$?

I also came to know that for deriving the differential equation governing motion of multi DOF system, Lagrange's equations will always lead to symmetric mass and stiffness matrices while the method using free body diagrams and Newton's law may give asymmetric matrices as well. So, is the matrix that we get from Lagrange's equation the symmetric component (I have mentioned before in my question what symmetric component is) of the matrix obtained from the free body diagram method?

Comment: Let me know if I have asked too many questions in one post and I will make separate posts for them.

Comment: Nothing in the linked post indicate that real dynamical systems may have non-symmetric mass matrices.

Answer (score 3):

your second question:

If you have two generalized coordinate $(q_1\,,q_2)$ the general case for the kinetic energy is:

$$T=\frac{1}{2}\,a\,\dot{q}_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\,b\,\dot{q}_2^2\pm\,c\,\dot{q}_1\,\dot{q}_2\tag 1$$

The mass matrix M is :

$$M=\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{\dot{q}}}\left(\frac{\partial\,T}{\partial \vec{\dot{q}}}\right)\tag 2$$

with $\vec{\dot{q}}=\left(\dot{q}_1\,,\dot{q}_2\right)^T$

thus:

$$M= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} a&\pm\,c\\\pm\,c&b
\end {array} \right]
$$
The mass matrix M is always symmetric

if  a,b,c are only depend on the system parameter and the  masses then M is constant.

If one of the parameter a or b or c depend on the generalized coordinates $q_i$ , then is the mass matrix not constant $M=M(q_i)$, but still symmetric!

**Stiffness matrix K**

for a linear spring forces the potential energy is:

$$U=\frac{1}{2}\,a\,{q}_1^2+\frac{1}{2}\,b\,\dot{q}_2^2\pm\,c\,{q}_1\,{q}_2\tag 3$$

Stiffness matrix K is:

$$K=\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{{q}}}\left(\frac{\partial\,U}{\partial \vec{{q}}}\right)\tag 4$$

with $\vec{{q}}=\left({q}_1\,,{q}_2\right)^T$

thus:

$$K= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} a&\pm\,c\\\pm\,c&b
\end {array} \right]
$$

If the parameters a,b,c are constant,the stiffness matrix K is symmetric and constant.

Edit:
**Example: Double Pendulum**

[image]
with the position vectors :

$$\vec{R}_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \rho\,\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) 
\\\rho\,\sin \left( q_{{1}} \right) \end {array}
 \right]
$$

$$\vec{R}_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \rho\,\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) +\rho\,
\cos \left( q_{{2}} \right) \\ \rho\,\sin \left( q_{
{1}} \right) +\rho\,\sin \left( q_{{2}} \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

you have two generalized coordinates $\vec{q}=[q_1\,,q_2]^T$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\vec{v}_1=\frac{\partial \vec{R}_1}{\partial \vec{q}}\dot{q}$$
$$\vec{v}_2=\frac{\partial \vec{R}_2}{\partial \vec{q}}\dot{q}$$

the kinetic energy is:

$$T=\frac{1}{2}\,m\left(\vec{v}_1\cdot\vec{v}_1+
\vec{v}_2\cdot\vec{v}_2\right)
={\rho}^{2}{{\dot{q}}_{{1}}}^{2}m+{\rho}^{2}m{\dot{q}}_{{1}}{\dot{q}}_{{2}
}\cos \left( q_{{1}}-q_{{2}} \right) +\frac{1}{2}\,{\rho}^{2}m{{\dot{q}}_{{2}}}
^{2}
$$

$$M=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} {\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial {x}^{2}}}T
 \left( x,y \right) &{\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial y\partial x}}T
 \left( x,y \right) \\ {\frac {\partial ^{2}}{
\partial y\partial x}}T \left( x,y \right) &{\frac {\partial ^{2}}{
\partial {y}^{2}}}T \left( x,y \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

with $x=\dot{q}_1$ and $y=\dot{q}_2$ you obtain

$$M=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 2\,{\rho}^{2}m&{\rho}^{2}m\cos \left( q_{{1
}}-q_{{2}} \right) \\ {\rho}^{2}m\cos \left( q_{{1}}
-q_{{2}} \right) &{\rho}^{2}m\end {array} \right] 
$$

thus M is symmetric and not constant.

I hope it is now clear?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand how has the expression for $T$, $U$, $M$ and $K$ that you wrote has been derived (eq. 1, eq. 2 and eq. 3). Could you please shed some light on that?

Comment: Also, this analysis seems to be based on Lagrange's approach, which according to my textbook will always give symmetric matrices; it is the free body diagram method (Newton's approach) that may not always give symmetric matrices and I have also seen an example when the mass matrix indeed comes out to be asymmetric. This is my main doubt as to why this happens and what's the relation between the two mass matrices we get from different approaches.

Comment: @ModCon I add example for you

Comment: This made things much clearer; thank you! Is there a general proof for why the first element of mass matrix is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}T(x, y)$ and so on?

Comment: this come from the equations of motion (EL) $M\,\vec{\ddot{q}}=\ldots$

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. I wish there was some way I could mark this as a partial answer.

Comment: Hey, I have a few more doubts related to analytical mechanics. May I ask them to you? If I may do so, please join this chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107874/analytical-mechanics

Answer (score 2):

Your second question is answered by [Lagrangian Mechanics](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/david-morin/files/cmchap6.pdf).

The equations of motion $M \ddot{x} + K x = 0$ are derived from the general equation

$$ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{x}} \right) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = 0 $$

where $T = \tfrac{1}{2} \dot{x}^\top M \dot x$ and $V = \tfrac{1}{2} x^\top K x$.

Specifically
  $$ \frac{\partial V}{\partial x}  = K x $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot x} = M \dot x $$

Your first question is unclear to me. I challenge you to find a real physical system that yields a non-symmetric mass matrix, nor a stiffness matrix.

The point being by the linked post is that *if it where* the case of non-symmetry, then those components would be simply ignored by the equations of motion and would bear no significance in the solution. You just have something there that is going to be multiplied by zero at some point, so why have it?

Comment: Thank you for answering. For an example of an asymmetric mass matrix, consider a double pendulum (of two slender rods) below a cart and let the generalised coordinates be $x$ (the position of cart, positive towards right), $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ (the angles of the rods from vertical, positive in the anti-clockwise direction).

Comment: The equations of motion for small motions, when Newton's laws and free body diagrams are used, are:
$$3m\ddot x +\frac{3}{2}mL\ddot \theta_1+\frac{mL}{2}\ddot \theta_2+kx=0$$
$$\frac{3}{2}mL\ddot x +\frac{13}{12}mL^2\ddot \theta_1+\frac{mL^2}{4}\ddot \theta_2+\frac{5}{2}mgL\theta_1=0$$
$$mL\ddot x +\frac{1}{2}mL^2\ddot \theta_1+\frac{mL^2}{3}\ddot \theta_2+\frac{1}{2}mgL\theta_2=0$$

Comment: @ModCon - there is something wrong with the equations above. I get the following system of equations in $M \ddot{q} = F$ which is clearly symmetric $$ \begin{bmatrix}3m & 2mL\cos\theta_{1} & mL\cos\theta_{2}\\
2mL\cos\theta_{1} & 2mL^{2} & mL^{2}\cos(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})\\
mL\cos\theta_{2} & mL^{2}\cos(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1}) & mL^{2}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x}\\
\ddot{\theta}_{1}\\
\ddot{\theta}_{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-kx\\
-2mgL\sin\theta_{1}\\
-mgL\sin\theta_{2}
\end{pmatrix}+\mathcal{O}(\dot{\theta}_{1}^{2},\,\dot{\theta}_{2}^{2}) $$

Comment: I reworked the entire thing and found the mistake; the matrix comes out to be symmetric indeed, sorry. Let me ask you exactly the root of this whole mess I have created: My textbook mentions "The FBD method, when applied to a MDOF linear system, occasionally leads to symmetric mass, stiffness and damping matrices". Is this true?
Once again sorry for taking your time and thank you for being patient.

Comment: The FBD method (assuming using Newtonian mechanics as opposed to Lagrangian mechanics) _always_ yields symmetric matrices unless the units are inconsistent (like using degrees vs. radians). I used the FBD method in the above comment to get the equations for example.

Comment: Got it...so the textbook is wrong.

Comment: @ModCon, not wrong, but omitting to make a point, which you correctly identified as missing, prompting you to ask here instead.